# How to fix my superkey to insert data into database?

Tags: sqlite

My table in SQLite uses an ID number and a date as a primary key/super key. The combination should be unique, but there can be duplicates of both within their respective columns.

I am using DBrowser for SQLite. When creating the table I checked a primary key box for both ID number and date. When I try to insert into the table, I get :

> Error importing data from record number ... Inserting row failed: UNIQUE constraint failed: table.ID, table.date

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're having indicates that there are duplicate values for the combination of the ID and date columns in your table, which violates the UNIQUE constraint defined by the primary key.
First try to remove the duplicate entries before importing the data into the table.

Then you need to modify the primary key constraint:

```sql
-- Drop the existing primary key constraint
ALTER TABLE Mytable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Mytable;

-- Add a new unique constraint for ID and date combination
ALTER TABLE Mytable ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Mytable_ID_date UNIQUE (ID, date);
```

Or use a composite primary key:

```sql
-- Create the table with a composite primary key
CREATE TABLE Mytable (
  ID INTEGER,
  date TEXT,
  -- Other columns...
  PRIMARY KEY (ID, date)
);
```

Just choose the option that suits your requirements best.